# How to plot postcodes and their 'centre of mass'

Tags: r, ggplot2, postal-code

I thought R would be good for this... but am a complete novice at it. I have a set of UK Postcodes (e.g. 'CB2 8UR') and a separate table that maps each postcode to an OS grid coordinate. Both start as CSV:

```
file1:
  "pcd"
  "CB2 8UR"
  "TE3 5LJ"

file2:
  "pcd","col2","col3","oseast1m","osnrth1m","col6",...
  ...
  "CB2 8UR","?","?",9823,2034,"?"
  ...
```

The real file1 has a thousand or so entries, and the real file2 has several hundred thousand (and about 20 columns). The only point of file2 here is to convert the postcode to a UK OS grid coordinate. At the moment, I think I can treat the coords as being on a 2d plane.

The task is to get a map with the 'centre of mass' of each postcode marked together with a heatmap representation of the postcodes.

I did manage to plot file2 data (i.e. all uk postcodes) as bins using qplot() + stat_bin2d():

```
m <- qplot(xlab="Longitude",ylab="Latitude",main="Postcode heatmap",geom="blank",x=pcd$oseast1m,y=pcd$osnrth1m,data=pcd)  + stat_bin2d(bins =200,aes(fill = log1p(..count..)))
```

where pcd is a data.frame read from file2.

So:

- How can I merge file1 and file to map just the codes in file1 but using the coords in file2?
- How can I calculate and add a marker for the centre of mass?
- If I wanted to mark some postcodes 'special' so their 'mass' was higher than normal, would that be simple to do?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that might help your progress.  First, based on the toy data frame, we use the `dplyr` package to merge the two data files based on the pcd variable.

Then it is beyond my familiarity, but I offer some code on finding the centroids of your data and plotting them.

```
library(dplyr)
post.codes <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2), pcd = c("CB2 8UR", "TE3 5LJ"))

coords <- data.frame(pcd = c("CB2 8UR", "TE3 5LJ"), coord1 = c("9823", "5555"),  coord2 = c("2034", "1234"), 
                    othervar = c("XYZ", "ABC"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

merged <- left_join(post.codes, coords, by = "pcd")
```

Next, use kmeans from the built-in stats package to find and add centroids.  This code is beyond pseudo code, I hope, but is only directional.

```
merged$centroid <- cbind(kmeans(merged$[the variable to cluster, 2)$cluster)

centroids <- df %>% group_by(centroid) %>% summarise(average = mean(centroid))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(centroids, aes([coord1, coord2, color=factor(notsurewhatgoes here))) +
  geom_point(size=3)+ geom_point(data=centroids, size=5)
```

Third, if you want to mark or highlight certain codes (centroids?), the general approach would be to create a new factor variable where the codes to be highlighted are TRUE and the others are FALSE.  Then in ggplot you do something based on that factor, such as `fill = highlight factor`.  All the TRUES will then have one fill color and all the rest will have the other default color.  You can use `scale_fill_manual(values = c("yourdesiredcolor", "yourseconddesiredcolor")` to pick the colors other than default